# How to host Artifactory in ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, artifactory

We are planning to host our Artifactory on ECS (Fargate) and mount the data to EFS. We will use an ALB in front of the containers (8081 and 8082) We still have some open issues:

- Can we use multiple containers at the same time or will there be upload/write issues to EFS?
- Is EFS a good solution or is S3 better?
- What about the metadata. I read Artifactory is hosting this in some Derby database. What if we redeploy a new container? Will the data be gone? Can this data be persisted on EFS or do we need RDS?

Comment: Have you considered [CodeArtifact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-maven.html)?  I moved from an EC2 JFrog to this and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can we use multiple containers at the same time or will there be upload/write issues to EFS?*
Ans: Yes you can use multiple containers to host Artifactory instances in a single host. However it is generally recommended to use multiple host to avoid the 'single point of failure' scenario. I don't anticipate any RW issues with EFS/S3.

*Is EFS a good solution or is S3 better?*
Ans: In my opinion both S3 and EFS are better known as scalable solutions rather than high performance oriented and it completely depends on the use-case. You can overcome this issue by enabling cache-fs in Artifactory which will store the frequently used binaries in a defined place (like a local disk with higher RW speeds). You can read more about cache-fs here: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-cache-fs-video/

*What about the metadata. I read Artifactory is hosting this in some Derby database. What if we redeploy a new container? Will the data be gone? Can this data be persisted on EFS or do we need RDS?*
Ans: when you are configuring more than one Artifactory node it is mandatory to have an external database (RDS) to store the configurations/references. On a side note: Artifactory generates the metadata for the packages/artifacts and store them in the FS only. However the references will be stored in the DB

Comment: Do I have to configure something special when I'll run multiple containers (and one DB + one bucket)?

Comment: hi @DenCowboy, I would suggest you to have a good local file system with healthy free disk to accomodate cache-fs.